# Raise a notification or alert on my Mac/PC as an IFTTT action?

Tags: ifttt

I am developing some bespoke software which will send updates to a WebHook monitored by IFTTT, so I can receive notifications. I would ideally like to be notified on my phone and on my Mac/PC with a prominent audible alert.

I cannot obviously see what actions are available for this beyond Notification, what options do I have? Is there a Mac/Windows IFTTT client for instance?

Answer (score 1):

You could have it run a python script and do what you want it to do. For example:
https://github.com/themoodymann/GoogleHome_IFTTT_RaspberryMatic

If that seems painful, you could have the IFTTT trigger send an email to a specific address and there are tools to do things based on receiving email. This may be easier but you may feel less adventurous !

Comment: Ah so the core of this is to use a WebHook Action that sends a message to my local IP address, and some kind of web-server listening. I can code that but it means opening a port on my firewall and having a static IP.

Comment: You could also modify that a bit and have the webhook call something in the cloud which you can catch from your computer. Examples are pubnub, MQTT, twilio, etc. Maybe even via a google spreadsheets api. There's also the 20 year old tech called email that I mentioned !